# checkLocationSettings on Pixel phones returns RESOLUTION_REQUIRED

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have three Pixel phones and they all display this behaviour when checking for location permissions in a fragment.

The result.isSuccessful() from checkLocationSettings method always returns false when wifi is off. I really don't understand it, its as if the Pixel doesn't know how to deal with location requests without wifi.

Note that if you turn scan wifi networks on, it'll start working as normal again.

This is the process my application takes:

1) Activity requests location permissions and they are granted. (This all works fine).

2) Fragment running later checks location permission granted and asks for location updates.

Fragment code:

```
locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
locationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
locationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);

LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new 
LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
SettingsClient client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(activity);
Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

task.addOnCompleteListener(result -> {
       if (result.isSuccessful()) {
           fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(
           ...
       }else{
           //Always end up here
           //com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResolvableApiException: 6: RESOLUTION_REQUIRED
           Exception locExcep = result.getException();
           Log.e(TAG, "startLocationUpdates failed: ", locExcep);
       }
```

Works on every other phone I can get my hands on. All code is almost identical to:

https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings.html

https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates

The error is:

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResolvableApiException: 6: RESOLUTION_REQUIRED
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(Unknown Source:3)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zai.zaf(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zaj.onComplete(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.zaa(Unknown Source:172)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.setResult(Unknown Source:131)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BaseImplementation$ApiMethodImpl.setResult(Unknown Source:36)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.location.zzbc.zza(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.location.zzar.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source:11)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.location.zzb.onTransact(Unknown Source:22)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
```

Comment: ANY SOLUTION TO THIS. Facing the same problem in a VIVO phone recently updated to Android 10.

Comment: Please any update?

Comment: Facing the same problem